# Let $G$ be the division graph on $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,12,14,16\}$. Does it have a hamilton/euler path?

Tags: graph-theory

> Given a graph G whose vertices are $V = \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,12,14,16\}$, and there is an edge between two vertices $w$ and $j$ iff $w\neq j$ and $w$ divides $j$ or $j$ divides $w$.
>
> (I) Does $G$ have a Hamilton path?
>
> (II) Does $G$ have an Euler path?

[image: The graph G]

Any help would be appreciated. For (I) I started looking for the path but couldn't find it, and tried to see what are the two most minimum degrees between two non-adjacent vertices and tried to see if it is $\geq 13$, but also that doesn't happen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Euler path is easy. Here are three vertices with odd degree:

- 4 -> 1, 2, 8, 12, 16 (5 neighbors)
- 10 -> 1, 2, 5 (3 neighbors)
- 12 -> 1, 2, 3, 4, 6 (5 neighbors)

A graph can have an Euler path only if at most two vertices have an odd degree. Hence, the graph does not contain an Euler path.

Trial-and-error gives this Hamilton-path: $$9 \rightarrow 3 \rightarrow 6 \rightarrow 12 \rightarrow 4 \rightarrow 8 \rightarrow 16 \rightarrow 2 \rightarrow 10 \rightarrow 5 \rightarrow 1 \rightarrow 7 \rightarrow 14$$

[image: The graph G and a Hamilton path]

Comment: Then my direction to try and actually find the Hamilton-path is correct, still, at time of the exam, and when pressure is at most, I doubt I could find it.
And regarding the Euler-path, does the theory say "A graph has an euler-path ***iff*** there are ***at most*** two vertices of odd degree?"

Comment: I can outline how I arrived at the Hamilton path. Observe that every pair of vertices on the path must be connected by their common multiple or common divisor. This gives us a unique sub-path 5 -> 1 -> 7. This can be 'extend'ed to 10 -> 5 -> 1 -> 7 -> 14. The only other number that can be connected to 10 must be 2, giving us 2 -> 10 -> 5 -> 1 -> 7 -> 14. The remaining numbers form chains 1) Multiples of 3: (9, 3, 6) and 2) Multiples of 2: (4, 8, 12, 16). A little rearrangement of them gives the required path.

Comment: And the Euler-path-condition is an $\textbf{iff}$ condition. Verified with Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated!